# CloudBlockBlob DownloadTextAsync Behavior Difference

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using an azure function with event grid trigger and CloudBlockBlob as input binding. The content is getting downloaded from CloudBlockBob using DownloadTextAsync(AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)

If the file being downloaded above is being generated using XmlDocument, DownloadTextAsync returns gibberish. However, if the file is generated by using FileStream, it works fine. PFB the implementations of generating the file-

1. Using XmlDocument

```
var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ContractName>), new XmlRootAttribute("RootAttributeName"));
serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, contractData);
var xmlString = stringwriter.ToString();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Save(fileName);
```

2. Using FileStream

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ContractName>), new XmlRootAttribute("RootAttributeName"));

var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);           
serializer.Serialize(file, contractData);
file.Close();
```

Code being used to download the content-

1. Using DownloadTextAsync

```
private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DownloadContentAsync_DownloadTextAsync(string storageAccountConnectionString, string containerName, string blobName)
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = GetContainer(storageAccountConnectionString, containerName);
            ICloudBlob blob = await container.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(blobName);

            // Download the blob content
            string xmlBlobContent =
                await (blob as CloudBlockBlob).DownloadTextAsync(
                    null,
                    new BlobRequestOptions { LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary },
                    new OperationContext());

            return xmlBlobContent;
        }
```

2. Using DownloadToStreamAsync

```
private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DownloadContentAsync_DownloadToStreamAsync(string storageAccountConnectionString, string containerName, string blobName)
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = GetContainer(storageAccountConnectionString, containerName);
            ICloudBlob blob = await container.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(blobName);

            // Download the blob content
            MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
            await (blob as CloudBlockBlob).DownloadToStreamAsync(
                resultStream,
                null,
                new BlobRequestOptions { LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary },
                new OperationContext());
            string xmlBlobContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultStream.ToArray());

            return xmlBlobContent;
        }
```

Why there is a difference in response from DownloadTextAsync.

Comment: Can you please try to use `DownloadToStreamAsync()` method instead of `DownloadTextAsync()`? It may add some extra things when using `XmlDocument`. And if it still occurs, please share us a minimal sample and working code.

Comment: @IvanYang Facing the same issue using DownloadToStreamAsync as well. Edited the question and added the sample code. Also added the code being used to git- https://github.com/chhavi28/TestDownloadBlobContent-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 0713:**

Figured it out. The root cause is that when you're using `XmlDocument` to generate the `xml` file, the encoding is `utf-16`. But for `FileStream`, it generates the xml file with encoding `utf-8`.

So, the solution is that, when using `XmlDocument`, we can specify the encoding to `utf-8`(no code change for `FileStream`). Sample code as below:

Generate xml file using `XmlDocument`:

```
               //2. Using XMLDoc
                serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, contractData);
                var xmlString = stringwriter.ToString();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
                doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                string fileName = String.Format(@"C:\TestBlobDownloadContent\UsingXMLDoc" + count + ".xml");

                //encoding as utf-8
                using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    doc.Save(sw);
                }
```

When read the xml file from blob storage via `DownloadTextAsync()` method, no need to specify the encoding option, like below:

```
        // Download the blob content
        string xmlBlobContent =
            await (blob as CloudBlockBlob).DownloadTextAsync(
                null,
                new BlobRequestOptions { LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary },
                new OperationContext());
```

---

**Original answer:**

This is due to the encode/decode issue.

Solution:

In the `DownloadTextAsync()` method, add parameter `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`. Like below:

```
 string xmlBlobContent =
             await (blob as CloudBlockBlob).DownloadTextAsync(
                            System.Text.Encoding.Unicode,
                            null,
                            new BlobRequestOptions { LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary },
                            new OperationContext());
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick help :) Although if we use encoding, the file generated using FileStream does not gets downloaded. The downloaded text for file generated using FileStream- 㼼浸⁬敶獲潩㵮ㄢ〮㼢ാ㰊潃瑮慲瑣汃獡敳⁳浸湬㩳獸㵩栢瑴㩰⼯睷⹷㍷漮杲㈯〰⼱䵘卌档浥ⵡ湩瑳湡散•浸湬㩳獸㵤栢瑴㩰⼯睷⹷㍷漮杲㈯〰⼱䵘卌档浥≡ാ 㰠潃瑮慲瑣汃獡㹳਍††值潲ㅰ显汩ㅥ⼼牐灯㸱਍††值潲㉰显汩ㅥ⼼牐灯㸲਍†⼼潃瑮慲瑣汃獡㹳਍⼼潃瑮慲瑣汃獡敳㹳

Comment: @user2848940, could you please upload the related code to your github? Then it will easy to troubleshoot. And please @ me if you done that:).

Comment: added the code to git. Changed the blobName and added the encoding

Comment: @user2848940, figured it out! Please refer to the updated section.